# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Visual Studio 2010 & SQL Server 2008 R2. I have created a project to sync SQL Server CE (`*.sdf`) file to SQL Server using a WCF service.

It is working fine when I have small SQL Server CE file (18 MB) but when I tried to sync using a large SQL Server CE file (38 MB) then an error happens.

I have increased size of many parameters in `web.config` of the WCF service & `app.config` of my application.

But the error keeps occurring.....

> *The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.*
>
> *StackTrace :*
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ServerSyncProviderProxy.GetChanges(SyncGroupMetadata groupMetadata, SyncSession syncSession)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent.DownloadChanges(SyncGroupMetadata groupMetadata)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent.DataSynchronize()
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent.Synchronize()
>   at SyncSample.AccountsListing.btnSync_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Which parameters did you change? "Many parameters" does not really give us much information.

Comment: In binding tag (closeTimeout="00:15:00", openTimeout="00:15:00", receiveTimeout="00:15:00", sendTimeout="00:15:00",                  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647",maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" In readerQuotas tag (maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647")
In reliableSession Tag(inactivityTimeout="00:15:00")

Answer (score 0):

Above exception means that there's something unexpected happened due to which connection is closed, and most of the time it's due to some exception on service side which caused to reject the request. You can enable WCF tracing for the service and check the logs to confirm the exception. Most of the time, exception message suggests you what went wrong ;-)

HTH,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

I was recently getting errors like this from a web service when I had not configured it correctly to handle enough data eg: maxBufferPoolSize, maxReceivedMessageSize and the like.

Also if you are sending a large array the service behaviour and endpoint behavior sections of these files may need:

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="array size here"/>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working. Actually one of my table have more then 1Lc records.. suggest me if you have any other solution.. Thnx ..

Answer (score 0):

as Amit suggested, you should try enabling WCF Tracing. the error you are getting can mean many things happening on the server side.

unless you're building a Windows Mobile app, I suggest you use the newer SqlSyncProvider/SqlCeSyncProvider/SyncOrchestrator combo as well instead of the older SqlCeClientSyncProvider/DBServerSyncProvider/SyncAgent (the same one used by Local Database Cache Project Item)

the newer providers has functionalities around batching if data size is really your problem.